# How to select all child nodes except text nodes?

Tags: xml, xpath

Given XML that looks something like this

```
 <FirstChild Orientation="Vertical">
    <SecondChild>Some text</SecondChild>
 </FirstChild>
```

and a binding that is using

```
XPath="child::node()"
```

I get output that looks like this

[image]

I don't want the text to appear in the tree

I tried using `not` like

```
XPath="child::node()[not(text())]"
```

as well as many variations, but haven't been able to nail it.

Anyone know how select all nodes *except* text nodes?

BTW, I do not want to exclude comments, only text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your XPath expression excludes all child nodes which contain a text node.

```
child::node()[not(text())]
```

Exclude nodes that are a text node *themselves*:

```
child::node()[not(self::text())]
```